# NEMA 6-15 to NEMA 6-20 A/C unit

Tags: electrical, receptacle, air-conditioning, cord-and-plug, voltage

My energy provider sent me a WiFi A/C system to hook up to my window unit, however, I cannot plug it into my wall because I appear to have a NEMA 6-15 outlet that matches the plug on my A/C unit and based on my attempt at internet research this WiFi thing looks to be a 6-20 plug. Would it be safe to simply get an adaptor so that I can plug this in?

Hopefully the images below work, as I’m not familiar with these things so images can probably speak better than I can!

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the receptacle on the front of this plug-in-widget your utility sent you?

Comment: Just added one.

Comment: I take it the receptacle's on a cord-pigtail?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t know what that means (I’m trying!) but I added a photo of the full WiFi widget if that’s what you’re asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

You have a few choices, none pretty.

### Rewire the circuit

If you are in a rental unit, this option is not available to you without landlord consent; and then; a licensed electrician must do it because it's a rental unit.

Since the socket is NEMA 6-15, it is fairly likely the wire and cable behind it are 14 AWG.  Open it up and have a look.  If you're very lucky and it's actually 12 AWG wire, you can skip to the last step.  Otherwise:

You will need to remove that wire/cable from there to the breaker panel and replace it with #12 wire or cable.   This won't be so bad if it's in conduit, but if it's cable-in-the-walls, it may be prohibitive.

Once there's #12 wire in the walls, you change the receptacle to NEMA 6-20 and the breaker to 2-pole 20A.

### Have them send you a different unit

NEMA 6-15 sockets are quite common for air conditioners.  The power company should have gotten more clear on your requirements. I am surprised they made this mistake.

Contact them, say they blew it, and you need one with a 6-15 plug and socket. They should oblige.

### Change the plug...?

Noting that the cable is inline on both ends, you could change both the plug and the socket to a NEMA 6-15 type.

*You can't leave the socket with a 6-20 because this would allow an appliance which requires a 20A circuit on a 15A circuit.  Even if it doesn't trip the breaker, it'll run the circuit beyond the design intent.  It breaks the whole system of coordination between Code requirements and UL listings that keeps appliances safe.*  So change the socket also to 6-15, even though you don't "need to right now".

Comment: Thank you! This is incredibly helpful. I will contact the power company. Oddly enough - they DID ask me what kind of outlet I have, but before I could respond they went and shipped me this one. Their mistake I suppose.

Comment: It looks like the socket might be on a cord. If so, you could potentially replace both the plug and the socket for 6-15 versions.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere see above -- the socket is indeed on a cord

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere So. Let’s say I ask the power company for a replacement and they say they don’t have one that fits my situation. Outside of rewriting the circuit (which I can’t do because it’s a rental), how difficult is replacing the plug and socket on the WiFi adapter?

Comment: *rewiring the circuit

Comment: @RebeccaHarris Changing the plug on the adapter is very easy.  Finding a replacement plug will be more of a challenge.  Not impossible, but if you want to find it locally it might take some searching.

Comment: @harper Upon reading this again, I'm actually not sure I'm following the last paragraph. The A/C unit has a 6-15 plug that is currently plugged into a 6-15 wall outlet. The WiFi adaptor has a 6-20 plug, so would the A/C unit not still be getting the same amount of power from the 6-15 wall outlet regardless of what type of plug the WiFi has? And apologies if this is a dumb question, just trying to understand because the power company confirmed they do not have a wifi thing that fits a 6-15 wall outlet out of the box and I was really looking forward to having remote controlled A/C!

Comment: @RebeccaHarris, yes, that's correct.  The male end on the device can be replaced to a 6-15 plug to fit your current socket.  If you do that, you're also supposed to replace the female plug with a 6-15, since it prevents someone else plugging a device that could overload the circuit, but personally, I wouldn't bother, since most likely you don't even own a device capable of that.  At worst, the breaker would trip -- no big deal.  But if you want to be extra safe, you can replace both with 6-15 ends.

Comment: We're supposed to give Code compliant answers (or explain why Code is wrong here), so I say replace them both.  A load which requires a 20A circuit will certainly draw between 12 and 16 amps (which is in-limits for continuous load on a 20A circuit, *but beyond continuous limits for a 15A*. Yet, the 15A breaker will tolerate it, mostly. You will occasionally get nuisance trips.  It's a weird edge condition that isn't supposed to exist.

Comment: They sell NEMA 6-15 plugs and sockets at most hardware stores. You have to replace both or you create a code violation if you ever upgrade to a larger A/C.  *You're not trying to make a cheater cable here, you're not here to say "Code is wrong, I hate code, I like house fires"*.  It's not far out of your way to do it right, so just do.